# Why cout a simple char* is not working?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, cout

I want you to look at the following two codes and tell me why the first one works and the other one doesn't.

First Code (Working):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char* getCoordinates(char* AndroidID)
{//Access the database and get the South Latitude value
    //This is here is dummy data for testing
    const char* S = "27.19122859";
    const char* N = "27.19245011";
    const char* W = "31.17657602";
    const char* E = "31.17657602";
    char X[100]="";
    strncat(X, "S", 1);
    strncat(X, S, strlen(S));
    strncat(X, "N", 1);
    strncat(X, N, strlen(N));
    strncat(X, "W", 1);
    strncat(X, W, strlen(W));
    strncat(X, "E", 1);
    strncat(X, E, strlen(E));
    char* Y = X;
    cout<<Y;
    return Y;
}
int main()
{
    char* sda=NULL;
    getCoordinates(sda);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints out correctly the string I want to compose

> S27.19122859N27.19245011W31.17657602E31.17657602

But when I try to do the same thing but print out the return value in main() things get a little weird
Second Code (Not working)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

char* getCoordinates(char* AndroidID)
{//Access the database and get the South Latitude value
    //This is here is dummy data for testing
    const char* S = "27.19122859";
    const char* N = "27.19245011";
    const char* W = "31.17657602";
    const char* E = "31.17657602";
    char X[100]="";
    strncat(X, "S", 1);
    strncat(X, S, strlen(S));
    strncat(X, "N", 1);
    strncat(X, N, strlen(N));
    strncat(X, "W", 1);
    strncat(X, W, strlen(W));
    strncat(X, "E", 1);
    strncat(X, E, strlen(E));
    char* Y = X;
    return Y;
}

int main()
{
    char* sda=NULL;
    char* T=getCoordinates(sda);
    cout<<T;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

> S27.       N27.19245011W31.`%@ \╞G ░■) $âG @■)

What is the problem here?

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string`, which would just work here?

Comment: [The compiler could have solved this.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69795df051f4d148)

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to an array of `char` which has lifetime only as long as the function.  When the function returns the array is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try to do it with a string then convert that string to a char* that is needed as an input to another function.

Comment: @SamerBastawy You can always use `c_str()` from a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

It dos not work because your function getCoordinates return pointer to buffer which has local scope of function getCoordinates and gets destroyed after the functions returns. Use std::string instead of char and it will be working.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate it